Displaying Solid Boundaries in Fluent: Slag Pot Simulation with Limited Mesh
I am working on an undergraduate thesis and I'm using Ansys Fluent to simulate the solidification of copper slag in a "slag pot" used in the process.
The query is, how can I include the solid so that it's displayed while solving the problem in Fluent? Considering that:
i. I have a limited number of cells in meshing due to the student version ii. Because of the above, I only mesh the fluid iii. But I need to have the walls of the slag pot to apply the boundary conditions iv. For the analysis, I need to see the solid when the calculations are finished



I am using Ansys 2024 Student Version.

Why not ask Ansys? They like helping students because they become future clients...
